# Entity Framework Mapping. Multiple Foreign keys

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, fluent-interface

I have two tables

```
People                  Relation
-------------           -----------------
Id (int)                Id (int)
Name (string)           ParentPeopleId (int)
                        ChildPeopleId (int)
```

I need to get all people by Relation table with union all.
The relation table has two foreign keys. And there is one problem with mapping them. The mapping is one to many. *People* has many *Relation*, *Relation* has one *People*.

I mapped them like this:

```
HasRequired(r=> r.People).WithMany(p=>p.Relation).HasForeignKey(r=>r.ChildPeopleId);
```

So, how can I map the second foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per each FK column in your `Relations` table you should have a navigation property in your `Relation` entity (this is not mandatory, but what is mandatory is have at least one navigation property between the entities involve in the relationship). In this case you have two relationships between `People` and `Relations`, and a navigation property represents one end in an relationship. Your model could be this way:

```
public class Relation
{
  public int Id {get;set;}

  public int ParentPeopleId {get;set;}

  public int ChildPeopleId {get;set;}

  public virtual People ParentPeople {get;set;}
  public virtual People ChildPeople {get;set;}
}
public class People
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}

   public virtual ICollection<Relation> ParentRelations {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Relation> ChildRelations {get;set;}

}
```

And the Fluent Api configurations like this:

```
HasRequired(r=> r.ParentPeople ).WithMany(p=>p.ParentRelations ).HasForeignKey(r=>r.ParentPeopleId);   
HasRequired(r=> r.ChildPeople).WithMany(p=>p.ChildRelations ).HasForeignKey(r=>r.ChildPeopleId );
```

Now if you don't want to work with one of the collection navigation properties in your `People` entity, you can create an unidirectional relationship. For example if you don't want `ParenRelations` navigation property, you can configure that relationship as follow:

```
HasRequired(r=> r.ParentPeople).WithMany().HasForeignKey(r=>r.ParentPeopleId);
```

### Update

Let me start first with a suggestion. I thing your table `Relation` is not playing any role is you have only those columns. If a person con only have a parent I would change your model to the following:

```
public class People
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}

   public int ParentId {get;set;}
   public virtual People Parent {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<People> Children {get;set;}
}
```

And you relationship configuration would be:

```
HasOptional(r=> r.Parent).WithMany(p=>p.Children).HasForeignKey(r=>r.ParentId);
```

Now going back to your [current model](http://pastebin.com/N2fs8Wjw), EF sees your `ChildPeopleId` property as an simple scalar column, it doesn't know it's a FK column, that's way I suggested above map two relationship instead one.

Another thing, with the below line

```
var Peoplelist = MyDbContext.People.Include(p=>p.Relations.Select(r=>r.People)).ToList();
```

You are telling to EF that you want to load the `Relation` entities related to a `People`, but also you want to load the `People` related with each `Relation`, which is at the same time the same `People` where the `Relation` came from, so, you don't need to do the last select, if your data is properly related, that `People` navigation property is going to be loaded when you execute your query,so, that query should be this way:

```
var Peoplelist = MyDbContext.People.Include(p=>p.Relations).ToList();
```

Comment: I need to get all child docs by People table. Trying this: `context.People.Include(p=>p.Relation)`
But got the same People not related

Comment: Did you check in your DB if you have `Relations` rows related with the `People` that you want to load?

Comment: Yes, I checked. The query returns the correct count of data but wrong data

Comment: Could you show your entities and the query you are calling?